# Hibernate Audit difference between find and createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I got a problem with audited entity.
A method used since several years don't work since few week.

For exemple we got 2 class like that

```
@Autited
class A {
   B object;
}

@Audited
class B {
   Integer id;
}
```

We used the method

```
@Override
public E getRevisionByPkAndRevisionNumber(Long pk, Integer revisionNumber) {
    final AuditQuery q =getAuditReader().createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(persistableEntityClass, revisionNumber).add(AuditEntity.id().eq(pk));
    return (E) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

When I try to get the revision of entity A i got it but not this property object.
A EntityNotFound is throw however it's exist !
But when i use the method

```
AuditReaderFactory.get(getEntityManager()).find(clazz, pk, revNumber);
```

Everything works fine and i got all attribute of the object...

What's the difference between the find method and the createQuery ?

Comment: Are you saying you persisted both `A` and `B` and then later query for the revisions for each separately, the query for `A` works but `B` does not?